# How do I resolve this issue regarding installing Intel Graphics Driver?

Tags: intel-graphics, intel

Each time I am opening the application Intel Graphics Installer, and attempting to install it I am getting the following error:

```
Ensuring consistent system... OKListing packages... OK
Setting up repositories... OK
Installing packages...
Updating package cache... Failed

With the following error

W:GPG error: https://download.01.org trusty Release: The following signatures were invalid: BADSIG A902DDA375E52366 Rodrigo Vivi (Intel Linux Graphics) <rodrigo.vivi@intel.com>, W:Failed to fetch 
, E:Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Answer (score 7):

To be able to download the graphic driver from Intel, you have to add their GPG keys to your system.  Ubuntu will otherwise be unable to validate that the files are correct.

To add the keys, open a terminal window and enter something like this:

```
wget --no-check-certificate https://download.01.org/gfx/RPM-GPG-KEY-ilg \
      -O - | sudo apt-key add -
```

or

```
wget --no-check-certificate https://download.01.org/gfx/RPM-GPG-KEY-ilg-2 \
     -O - | sudo apt-key add -
```

**Note** Intel seem to update their GPG keys regularly, and [their instructions](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/intel-graphics-installer-linux-1.4.0) do not get updated as often leading to [forum posts](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/forum/graphics-installer-discussions/new-ubuntu-16.04-packages-use-unknown-key-again) complaining. However, if you don't mind guesses, you'll note that the difference between the two keys above is `-2` appended to the URL. For 16.04's packages at least as of 14 Oct 2016, Intel are on `-4`. My bet is that the next one's likely to be `-5`!